# cellForItem(at: IndexPath) method doesn't call with UICollectionViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In Xcode, I have created a var "userImage" in userCell - subclass of UICollectionViewCell.

```
import UIKit

class userCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
}
```

Now I want to implement cellForItem(at: IndexPath) method on my collection view, but the cell it returns doesn't have that "userImage" var.

Code below:

```
self.collection.cellForItem(at: path).userImage.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
```

Gives error " Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell?' has no member 'userImage' "

Code below:

```
self.collection.cellForItem(at: path) as userCell.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
```

Gives error " Var 'userImage' is not a member type of 'userCell' "

Answer (score 0):

Your code infers to **UICollectionViewCell** which has no property with that name , so you must explicitly cast it to **userCell** with **?** as that cell may be nil to avoid crashes

```
 let cell = self.collection.cellForItem(at: path) as? userCell

 cell?.userImage.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
```

also make sure that userImage is properly connected to the imageView in cell Xib

Comment: Additionally class name should starts with uppercase so correct name is "UserCell". Using "userCell" suggest that it is instance of class.

Comment: I have done it but swift complains that userImage is optional, with exclamation mark the app crashes because the value of userImage is nil, with question mark nothing happens

Comment: first check if that cell is nil or not as it may be not currently displayed

Comment: let foto = UIImage(data: data!)
                            if let cc = self.collection.cellForItem(at: path) as? UserCell{
                                if let userimage = cc.userImage {
                                    userimage.image = foto
                                }else{
                                    print("userimage is nil")
                                }
                            }else{print("cell is nil")}


prints "userimage is nil" in console

Comment: userimage may not be connected to imageView in xib